# fopen takes more time with "w" than "a" mode

Tags: c++, c

Does fopen and fclose take more time when opened in "w" mode than "a" mode for the following conditions
1. file already present
2. No file present
something on the lines of the following 
     logFile = fopen(log,"a");
           and
     logFile = fopen(log,"w");

I have the following code which I did a quick strace profiling on to get the clock cycles on each system call with no file present at the start of test.

### code

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char* log = "log.txt";
    FILE* logFile = NULL;
    char timeBuf[100];
    time_t now;
    struct tm *logtime1;

    time(&now);
    logtime1 = localtime(&now);
    strftime(timeBuf,sizeof(timeBuf),"[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]",logtime1);
    int i;
    char *inMessage = "The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog";
    for(i=0;i<50000;i++)
    {
        logFile = fopen(log,"a"); //or **logFile = fopen(log,"w");**
        if(logFile != NULL)
        {
           fflush( 0 );
           int error = 0;

           fprintf(logFile, "%s\t%s %d at (%s:%d)\n",timeBuf,
           inMessage, error,__FILE__, __LINE__);
           fclose(logFile);
        }
   }
   return 0;
```

}

---

When I open the file in "w" mode strace profiling is showing that it takes way more time in open system call. Is there a reason behind that ?

Below are the two profiles

1. ---------- **strace on code with "w" mode**

   strace -c ./test.out -o report

   % time     seconds  usecs/call    calls    errors syscal

   ---

   76.17    0.522555          10     50006           open

   12.13    0.083197           2     50006           close

   4.61    0.031626           1     50000           write

   3.96    0.027151           1     50002           munmap

   1.57    0.010737           0     50017           mmap

   1.55    0.010663           0     50007           fstat

   ---

   100.00    0.686068                300060         1 total

   2. **strace on code with "a" mode**

   ---------- strace -c ./test.out -o report

   % time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall

   ---

   22.08    0.020467           0     50002           munmap

   20.24    0.018763           0     50000           write

   16.76    0.015542           0    100007           fstat

   13.43    0.012450           0     50006           open

   9.90    0.009177           0     50006           close

   9.44    0.008756           0     50017           mmap

   8.15    0.007558           0     50001           lseek

   ---

   100.00    0.092713                400060         1 total

Comment: `w` will truncate the file you're opening. if it's a "big" file, it'll take a while for the OS to clean up.

Comment: I think opening a file performance depends more on the operating system implementation since it is a system call.

Comment: makes sense that truncation of the file in "w" mode will take the OS some cycles(implementation dependent).
Thanks

Comment: What you're trying to measure depends a lot on the implementation; "a" and "w" do different things not necessarily comparable. And consider that when timing a program, measurements should be repeated several times under different conditions: consider that the OS needs time to find a file in disk, but subsequent accesses will be faster because of cached information and maybe even the disk heads being closer to the file contents. Which is to say, your 1st program running from cold boot can end up paying for I/O overhead and take longer than the 2nd program.

Comment: I agree with you, but just to let you know I profiled for both implementations multiple times with similar results. Also I thought with the code running for 50000 iterations I could disregard the initial I/O overhead for both implementations.
Can I not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With mode="w", the file is emptied before the write, so the system must :

1. Reset the size of the file to zero (open)
2. Mark the blocks used on disk as unused (open)
3. Allocate a new block (write)
4. Update file size (write)

With mode="a", the system only has :

3. Allocate a new block (sometimes, not always, if what you write goes into a new block)
4. Update file size (write)

Obviously, mode="w" doing more work will take more time...